# Transferring data by date from email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, vlookup

I'm fairly new to coding in Google Script, and with Javascript. Basically what I'm trying to do is make a script to update data on a table in a spreadsheet. I have the script to import the email as a CSV, but I'm struggling with transferring the data from the email to the table by matching up the dates. Essentially what I would like the script to do is emulate a vlookup and paste the values from the emails CSV file to the table.

I made a copy of the file as an example of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to transfer the yellow section of columns A and B of the Data tab to the matching yellow section columns A and B. And if there is no data for the dates then I would like the empty dates to be 0.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uK3sCUFvcW6lgk962jgTN-yZox-lF8-Z0wm7Zhh-i8I/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: Check Script Services/Utilities for Utilities that will convert csv to object[][] Once they're in an array of arrays it's pretty easy to do a lot of things with them.  But if you don't know Javascript that makes things more difficult.  Perhaps you should consider some introductory tutorials.  Check the Google Apps Script documentation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two functions will accomplish your objectives. `createArray(hight, width, filling)` is just a workaround to create an array of the exact size of the Destination table. `moveDates()` is the one that compares the timestamps of the Data table with the ones on Destination; and will write down the values of the row if they match, and a zero if they don't.

This second function will first declare a bunch of variables that will save ranges and values for both sheets. After that, it will read all the dates of both tables. Later, it will run through the Destination table searching for coincidences and saving them on the `newData` array. Finally, the code will write down the `newData`. I've tested this code on your spreadsheet and it works perfectly.

```
function createArray(hight, width, filling) {
  var array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < hight; i++) {
    array[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      array[i][j] = filling;
    }
  }

  return array;
}

function moveDates() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    'Destination');
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(5, 1, 6, 3);
  var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(2, 1, 11, 3);
  var newDataRange = destinationSheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 2)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var destination = destinationRange.getValues();
  var dataDates = [];
  var destinationDates = [];
  var newData = createArray(11, 2, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataDates.push(new Date(data[i][0]));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < destination.length; i++) {
    destinationDates.push(new Date(destination[i][0]));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < destination.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (destinationDates[i].getTime() === dataDates[j].getTime()) {
        newData[i][0] = data[j][1];
        newData[i][1] = data[j][2];
      }
    }
  }

  newDataRange.setValues(newData);
}
```

If you need more information or clarifications I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thank you for the assistance in this issue!